# Cannot change datatype in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently attempting to change the datatype of my pandas column.
I'm running python3.7 on google Colab.

```py
df = df.astype({"Style 1": str, "Style 2": str})
print(df["Style 1"].dtype)
```

`object` is printed out.

Furthermore, while attempting to call the `Series.replace` method, I get an error related to not being the correct type.

```py
for x in Styles: # enum
  df["Style 1"].replace(x.name, x.value)
  df["Style 2"].replace(x.name, x.value)
```

```bash
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-101b5f03f8b5> in <module>
      3 print(df["Style 1"].dtype)
      4 for x in Styles:
----> 5   df["Style 1"].replace(x.name, x.value)
      6   df["Style 2"].replace(x.name, x.value)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in replace(self, to_replace, value, inplace, limit, regex, method)
   6612                 else:
   6613                     raise TypeError(
-> 6614                         f'Invalid "to_replace" type: {repr(type(to_replace).__name__)}'
   6615                     )
   6616 

TypeError: Invalid "to_replace" type: 'str'
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is `Styles`? You are supposed to give a reproducible sample of your data.

Comment: You will need to edit your post to provide the code giving the error and explain exactly what it is you are trying to achieve. Hard to help otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can try series.replace function with **str**;

```
df["Style 1"].str.replace(x.name, x.value)
```

Comment: Yep, this works if I want to replace with just a string. But x.value is a list of integers, any idea of how I can achieve this?

Comment: If ```Styles``` is an enum then you can't have multiple values per name.